# XSLT: apply templates inside copy of the element

Tags: xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0

I need to output copy of element with all its attributes and apply-templates on children inside.
main problem is that attributes are unknown.

XML:

```
<elem attrA="a" attrB="b" ... attrN="n">
  <child><child>
  <child><child>
</elem>
```

I have attempted to loop over all attributes but, can't get it working.

```
<xsl:template match="elem">
  <xsl:element name="name(.)">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="name()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Required output:

```
<elem attrA="a" attrB="b" ...="" attrN="n">
  <processed-child></processed-child>
  <processed-child></processed-child>
</elem>
```

Given child template:

```
<xsl:template match="child">
  <processed-child><xsl:value-of select="."/></processed-child>
</xsl:template>
```

Edit:

XSLT 1.0

Comment: @Tomalak, <xsl:attribute name="name()"> results in error: The '(' character, hexadecimal value 0x28, cannot be included in a name..

Comment: Try  `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">` But the answer from Tomalak is even better.

Comment: That's because it must be `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">` - note the curly braces. They are [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), you forgot them. The same goes for `<xsl:element name="{name()}">`, of course.

Comment: @Tomalak, hr_117, I knew about attribute value templates, but didn't realize I can use them inside some xsl elements attributes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does

```
<xsl:template match="elem">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

not work?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Tomalak's answer, the final solution was enhanced a bit to enable text rendering around tags. (It was not described in original post, but was a requirement)

Complete solution:

```
<xsl:template match="elem">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>
```